# Textile renders to HTML, but Django is escaping it

Tags: django

I have a bunch of posts stored in text files formatted in yaml/textile (from Jekyll) that I am trying to import into my new Django project. The problem is that Django is escaping the actual html code, meaning my post is not getting formatted. How can I got about fixing this? should I change something in the jekyll-import command (a custom manage.py command), the postgresql server, or the views.py file?

Example:

```
 The one thing I can&#8217;t do is write about myself. Hell, look at my <a href="http://colegleason.github.com/about.html">about me page.</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured it out right after I posted it.  I had tried this before but used the wrong syntax. To do this I just had to add '|safe' to the end of my body tag.

Like so:

```
{{ body|safe }}
```

Very nice.